# Joomla 3.4.4 - URL Problems with alias of products in submenu

Tags: joomla-3.x, virtuemart, language, alias

I am writing for help regarding a problem with incorrect alias in the URL for product content from my Italian submenu. I created a submenu for products in my website (the products are with VirtueMart). For example in Italian I get this:

```
wwww.mysite.com/it/vini/nord-italia/2016-04-29-14-43-42/dolcetto
```

while the English menu correctly displays as:

```
wwww.mysite.com/en/wines/north-italy/piedmont-wines/dolcetto-d-alba-doc
```

So to summarize, the English language alias appears in the URL as it should (not numbered) the problem is that the Italian language part of the alias is numbered (it contains date and time and it shouldn't). Why is this happening? How can I fix it?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 3):

I FOUND THE SOLUTION!!!

> Temporary change menu item type to Text Separator, modify alias to
>   your liking and change type back to External URL.
>   REFERENCE:http://www.mysysadmintips.com/other/web/285-remove-date-and-time-from-joomla-menu-link-url

Thanks to all for the help. ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Have you check the alias In Menu item?
2. Did you try Menu >> Rebuild

Rebuild. Reconstructs and refreshes the relevant table. Normally, you do not need to rebuild this table. This function is provided in case the data in the table becomes corrupted.

https://docs.joomla.org/Help35:Menus_Menu_Item_Manager

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try to rebuild the item (external link) of my menu but without success. The alias remain always the usual. How could I do? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the alias from your category? Maybe the category have different alias and joomla create this alias In your url.

Answer (score 1):

Update to 3.4.8 and run the rebuild menu command.

Seriously update to 3.4.8 as soon as possible (I'm not saying that will fix your menu issue, but it will improve the security of your site)